# Getting two points' positions on a circle

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: A quick math question in unity]

The known factors are O (center of the circle), R (radius), and X's position(and the distance between X and O naturally).

What I need to get here are the intersecting points of the straight line which always is perfectly vertical or horizontal. The circle is not a collider but just visual representation to show. Another fact in this is that X is always inside the range(within the radius) of the circle which means both x1 and x2 will always be at the radius distance from O.

Time to time I get really bummed out when trying to utilize known mathematical equations with coding and this is no different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly,

`X` is a "random" point **inside** your circle whose position is known : `X = (X.x, X.y)`.

Supposing you want to know `X1` and `X2` on the circle so that `(X1X2)` is a vertical line. You **know** the absicca of those points which is `X.x`.

You surely know that the coordinates of a point on a circle can be defined as : `A = (O.x + r * cos θ, O.y + r * sin θ)` where :

- `O` is the origin of the circle
- `r` is the radius of your circle
- `θ` is an angle in radians.

Thus,

```
X1 = (O.x + r * cos θ1, O.y + r * sin θ1) = (X.x, O.y + r * sin θ1)
```

which means

```
    X.x = O.x + r * cos θ1
<=> cos θ1 = (X.x - O.x) / r <=> θ1 = arcos( (X.x - O.x) / r )
```

Once you know `θ1`, computing `sin θ1` and `X1.y` is a piece of cake.

Computing `X2` is very easy, you just have to invert the ordinate.

---

If `(X1X2)` is an **horizontal** line, you know the ordinates of `X1` and `X2` :

```
X1 = (O.x + r * cos θ1, O.y + r * sin θ1) = (O.x + r * cos θ1, X.y)

    X.y = O.y + r * sin θ1
<=> sin θ1 = (X.y - O.y) / r <=> θ1 = arcsin( (X.y - O.y) / r )
```

Here, to get `X2` you have to invert the absicca.

Comment: O.o Whoa.... I think you understood just perfectly!
I'll get to coding with this! Great thanks!